# How do I extract login history?

Tags: linux, login

I need to know the login history for specific user (i.e. login and logout time),
How do I extract this history for a specific date range in Linux ?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can try the `last` command:

```
last john
```

It prints out the login/out history of user john. Whereas running just

```
last
```

prints out the login/out history of all users.

Comment: This only returns values for the current month in most Linux distros.

Answer (score 44):

If you need to go further back in history than one month, you can read the `/var/log/wtmp.1` file with the `last` command.

`last -f wtmp.1 john` will show the previous month's history of logins for user `john`.

The last log output isn't too heavy and relatively easy to parse, so I would probably pipe the output to grep to look for a specific date pattern.

`last john | grep -E 'Aug (2[0-9]|30) '` to show August 20-30. Or something like:

`last -f /var/log/wtmp.1 john | grep -E 'Jul (1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30) '` to acquire July 10-30 for user `john`.

Answer (score 22):

> How to extract login history for specific date range in Linux?

An example to list all users login from 25 to 28/Aug:

```
last | while read line
do
    date=`date -d "$(echo $line | awk '{ print $5" "$6" "$7 }')" +%s`
    [[ $date -ge `date -d "Aug 25 00:00" +%s` && $date -le `date -d "Aug 28 00:00" +%s` ]] && echo $line
done
```

- `awk '{ print $5" "$6" "$7 }'` to extract the date time at corresponding column from `last` output
- `+%s` to convert datetime to Epoch time
- `-ge` stand for greater than or equal
- `-le` stand for less than or equal

You can also do it for specific user with `last <username>`.

Comment: That's a mighty-ugly expression. Wouldn't grep be cleaner since `last` output is pretty readable?

Comment: Can you `grep` from "Aug 15 09:00" to "Aug 25 21:00"?

Comment: The OP didn't ask for time ranges.

Comment: Could you filter from "Jul 19" to "Aug 11" by `grep`?

Comment: @ewwhite the expression looks beautiful to me, if you dont like the look of bash syntax this may not be the site for you.

Comment: @ekerner You're right. I'll go somewhere else ;)

Comment: Note that the "equal to or less than" function does NOT work; i.e. I have to choose May 16 in order to include logins from May 15.  I'm not sure if this also applies to the first one as well.  In any case, great answer and thanks!